# Converting a column of credit ratings like AAA BB CC to a numeric category of AAA = 1, BB = .75 etc in python?

Tags: python, categorical-data

I have a column in a dataframe called 'CREDIT RATING' for a number of companies across rows. I need to assign a numerical category for ratings like AAA to DDD from 1(AAA) to 0(DDD). is there a quick simple way to do this and basically create a new column where i get numbers 1-0 by .1's? Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use replace:

```
df['CREDIT RATING NUMERIC'] = df['CREDIT RATING'].replace({'AAA':1, ... , 'DDD':0})
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply create a dictionary mapping:

```
mymap = {"AAA":1.0, "AA":0.9, ... "DDD":0.0}
```

and then apply it to the dataframe:

```
df["CREDIT MAPPING"] = df["CREDIT RATING"].replace(mymap)
```

Comment: You will need to create the mapping manually since Python cannot know the order of the ratings, e.g. whether AA is better than DDD.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was kinda though without nothing to work with but here we go:

```
# First getting a ratings list acquired from wikipedia than setting into a dataframe to replicate your scenario

ratings = ['AAA' ,'AA1' ,'AA2' ,'AA3' ,'A1' ,'A2' ,'A3' ,'BAA1' ,'BAA2' ,'BAA3' ,'BA1' ,'BA2' ,'BA3' ,'B1' ,'B2' ,'B3' ,'CAA' ,'CA' ,'C' ,'C' ,'E' ,'WR' ,'UNSO' ,'SD' ,'NR']
df_credit_ratings = pd.DataFrame({'Ratings_id':ratings})

df_credit_ratings = pd.concat([df_credit_ratings,df_credit_ratings]) # just to replicate duplicate records

# The set() command get the unique values
unique_ratings = set(df_credit_ratings['Ratings_id'])
number_of_ratings = len(unique_ratings) # counting how many unique there are
number_of_ratings_by_tenth = number_of_ratings/10 # Because from 0 to 1 by 0.1 to 0.1 there are 10 positions.

# the numpy's arange fills values in between from a range (first two numbers) and by which decimals (third number)
dec = list(np.arange(0.0, number_of_ratings_by_tenth, 0.1))
```

After this you'll need to mix the unique ratings to it's weigths:

```
df_ratings_unique = pd.DataFrame({'Ratings_id':list(unique_ratings)}) # list so it gets one value per row
```

EDIT: as Thomas suggested in another answer's comment, this sort probably wont fit you because it won't be the real order of importance of the ratings. So you'll probably need to first create a dataframe with them already in order and no neet to sort.

```
df_ratings_unique.sort_values(by='Ratings_id', ascending=True, inplace=True) # sorting so it matches the order of our weigths above.
```

Resuming the solution:

```
df_ratings_unique['Weigth'] = dec # adding the weigths to the DF

df_ratings_unique.set_index('Ratings_id', inplace=True) # setting the Rantings as index to map the values bellow

# now this is the magic, we're creating a new column at the original Dataframe and we'll map according to the `Ratings_id` by our unique dataframe
df_credit_ratings['Weigth'] = df_credit_ratings['Ratings_id'].map(df_ratings_unique.Weigth)
```